# The method getOrDefault(String, String) is undefined for the type Map<String,String>

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

in the following code I get an error at the return of the namespaceMap. Don't know why. getOrDefault Methode should be defined in HashMap.class. I tried to create an NamespaceMapper as described in the linked example https://www.intertech.com/Blog/jaxb-tutorial-customized-namespace-prefixes-example-using-namespaceprefixmapper/

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

 public class FimsNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

 private Map<String, String> namespaceMap = new HashMap<>();

 public FimsNamespacePrefixMapper() {
    namespaceMap.put("http://base.fims.tv", "bms");
    namespaceMap.put("http://transformmedia.fims.tv", "tms");
 }

 @Override
 public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
    return namespaceMap.getOrDefault(arg0, arg1);
 }}
```

Comment: And what exception you got?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? The method was introduced with Java 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getOrDefault` method was introduced in Java 8. Check which runtime version of Java you are using by running `java -version`. If you are using something lower than Java 8 (1.8), upgrade and your code should work.